# WIX installer shows brackets in status line

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am using a WIX installer that is showing some brackets in the status line (see image below):

[image: Installer screenshot]

I haven't made changes to the WIX file, but only the installed files have changed. I did update WIX to v3.11, because this was required to use WIX in Visual Studio 2017. We use the standard `WixUI`.

These strings are listed in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\SDK\wixui\WixUI_en-us.wxl` file. A few lines from this file:

```
<String Id="ProgressTextRemoveFiles" Overridable="yes"><!-- _locID_text="ProgressTextRemoveFiles" _locComment="ProgressTextRemoveFiles" -->Removing files</String>
<String Id="ProgressTextRemoveFilesTemplate" Overridable="yes"><!-- _locID_text="ProgressTextRemoveFilesTemplate" _locComment="ProgressTextRemoveFilesTemplate" -->File: [1], Directory: [9]</String>
```

These strings exactly match what I see during installation. It seems only the `ProgressDlg` has this issue, but maybe other strings don't use expansion. Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WiX: "Copying new files File: \[1\], Directory: \[9\], Size \[6\]" shown during installation of an MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161526/wix-copying-new-files-file-1-directory-9-size-6-shown-during-instal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the following line in your main wxs:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
```

See [my answer for the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44182276/217666).