# WiX: "Copying new files File: [1], Directory: [9], Size [6]" shown during installation of an MSI

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Recently, I noticed the strange text mesages during installation of our MSI created in WiX 3.11 + VS 2017. I'm seeing "**Copying new files File: [1], Directory: [9], Size [6]**" text:

[image]

Similarly, I'm getting the following during uninstallation:

[image]

This happens on the latest Windows 10 Pro build 15063.296. I think I didn't notice this problem before. I tried the same installer on Win 7 that was not updated for some time and it worked correctly (or better):

[image]

I think I'm not alone, according to the [screenshot on this page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-cli-2-0-new-commands-features-available-now-in-azure-cloud-shell/). But I couldn't find any information.
Did you experience the same problem? If yes, is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the solution. All I needed was to add the following line inside the <Product> tag in my main wxs:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
```

**Explanation**

Without the above mentioned line, my MSI package was using the stock messages inside Windows Installer for ActionText, see [this tutorial](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface/ui-wizardry/). It seems, that in earlier versions of Windows, these messages were identical to those supplied by Wix. That's why I got the correct "**Copying new files**" in Win 7 but incorrect "**Copying new files File: [1], Directory: [9], Size [6]**" in the latest Win 10.

After adding a reference to WixUI_ErrorProgressText, the messages defined by Wix are used (these messages are correct) and everything is OK.

**Note**

In Wix, there's the following template defined as well (and this has confused me at first):

"**File: [1], Directory: [9], Size [6]**"

But if you expect to see the file names and their sizes during installation, you're wrong. The [ProgressDlg](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/ProgressDlg.wxs) in Wix doesn't display it. If you want this info, you need to [override that dialog](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html) and add the ActionData text explicitly. I didn't test it. See how it's done in [PrepareDlg](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/PrepareDlg.wxs).

Comment: I noticed this behavior after the Windows 10 Creators Update, did anyone find out what exactly changed there?

Comment: Same here - also after updating to Win10 Creators Update.

Comment: Experienced the same issue after updating to W11 and successfully fixed it adding that reference.

Comment: This is happening on Windows 11 and adding the UIRef did not work for me.   The referenced fragment has the exact same formatting strings as the default.  See https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/473562c0c3904216f2b6963c0ad244a8cc41e9ee/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_en-us.wxl

Comment: @wta: It should work. Which strings do you mean? There is `ProgressTextInstallFiles` with the correct value: `Copying new files`. As I wrote in my answer, there are other texts, such as `ProgressTextInstallFilesTemplate`, but they are not used out of the box. If you want to use them, read the last note in the answer.

Comment: @Peter Macej: I don't want to see the template text at all; just the description text.   On Windows 11 I am still getting the raw template string displayed instead of just the description.  I was under the impression that using the UIRef would revert to the WIn7-like behavior described above; i.e. just the description text of the action and no template text.   I guess I need to override the template string for each action to be blank to get the original behavior.

Comment: It works. The tag <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" /> must be placed AFTER the dialog library reference (e.g. <UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced" /> )