# Windows Installer progress bar message placeholders "[1]" are not substituted

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer

We have a Wix-based installer that's been working fine until recently. When we install it on the Windows Creator Update, the progress bar messages do not substitute real values for placeholders. Messages that are supposed to be formatted are now just shown literally. Examples:

```
Copying new files File: [1], Directory: [9], Size: [6]
Starting services Service: [1]
Writing system registry values Key: [1], Name: [2], Value: [3]
```

Why aren't the bracketed placeholders being replaced with actual values?

Other facts: The same kit works fine on other versions of Windows. We build for .NET 4.0. Windows Creators Update uses NET Framework 4.7. We're going to do more testing to see if our recent upgrade to .NET 4.0 may be at fault (it isn't a problem on other versions of Windows).

*Addendum*
Another kit predating our conversion to .NET 4.0 also has this failure mode on Creators Update.

I'm going to cross-post this to the wix-users list and will post a summary answer back here if I get one.

Comment: Someone else has observed the same behavior using a later version of Wix. Possibly it's a bug in Wix going back at least to 3.5. The other possibility is it's a Windows C.U. bug.

Comment: I also am seeing the same problem.  Installers that have been built work fine on other Windows operating systems but on Windows creator the properties are not being substituted.   Has anyone a solution?  I've tried bumping our version of Wix to the latest 3.11 but this has the same issue

Comment: It seems to be related to C:U, same problem appeared for me after the update. Could you post a link to your question on the wix-users list so we can look at people's findings there as well?

Comment: Here you go @Ewoud. No answers there, just some me-toos.http://lists.wixtoolset.org/pipermail/wix-users-wixtoolset.org/2017-June/004973.html

Comment: @Bob Thank you! Maybe you can report the solution I posted below to them?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161526/wix-copying-new-files-file-1-directory-9-size-6-shown-during-instal/44182276#44182276):

Add `<UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />` inside the product tag of your .wxs file to properly show the messages.

It seems that this sets the installer to use its own messages instead of the default Windows messages that seem to have disappeared in the Creators Update. If someone can find a source that explains this, that would be great!