# Wix setup error 2612: Stream not found in '[2]' column. Primary key: '[3]'

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am getting an error while installing setup for my application...

Error:
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. This error code is 2612.

What could be an issue? Please help!

Comment: There must be something missing in your action text or Progress dialog because it's not showing the database column or the table key in those brackets number places. It could be data from the Binary table or something else. You may need to show your WiX source. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020673/wix-installer-shows-brackets-in-status-line

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my case I had couple of shortcuts which were pointing to icon files (Help.ico) but they were not really icon files. Few weeks ago, I renamed Help image file (.png or .jpg) to Help.ico for some reason and setup was pointing to those files. Incorrect stream...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, I had couple of shortcuts which were pointing to icon files (Help.ico) but they were not really icon files. Few weeks ago, I renamed Help image file (.png or .jpg) to Help.ico for some reason and setup was pointing to those files. Incorrect stream...

```
            <Shortcut Id="StartMenuItemHelp" Name="Application Help" Directory="ProgramMenuDir"
                    WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Icon="Help.ico" Advertise="yes">
                <Icon Id="Help.ico" SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)\SetupFiles\Help.ico" />
            </Shortcut>
```